On the OEIS sequence A020639
This question relates to https://oeis.org/A020639.
Given a composite number $n$, how to find the least prime dividing $n$ efficiently?
Since the goal is just the least prime, it is not necessary to factorize $n$ completely.
Hence, there are two possible methods -- incomplete factorization method and complete factorization method.
If $n$ is small, choosing which method is not important because their performances are quite similar.
However, for bigger cases, one might be far more efficient than the other.
So I need a rule to predict which method is better if $n$ is known.
Could you help me? Thanks!

Generally it's no easier than factorization, since iterating the algorithm computes  a factorization.
